# Android Edittext question, replace keypad enter with done

Tags: xml, android

I'm defining an edit text like so...

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/user"
android:layout_width="200px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Username"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_x="64px"
android:layout_y="140px"
>
```

I'd like to replace the "enter" button that appears on the keypad automatically, with a done button that would just close the keypad when the user hits it. I've seen this done on a couple of apps (e.g the Nexus One twitter app) and would like to implement something similar. does anyone know how?

Also is it possible to get the text that appears by default to auto erase when the user click to edit the edittext box?
Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple solution: add `android:singleLine="true"` for the EditText. This will replace the enter with Next (for all edittexts except the last one) and Done (for the last one).

Comment: that worked! thanks! one more thing, how would I turn off dictionary?

Comment: use `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Comment: btw, you can set a custom action instead of the default one (next/done) with `android:imeOptions`

Answer (score 9):

Just add in the EditText XML : `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an updated answer:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

The accepted answer of `android:singleLine="true"` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

It replaces the name of the enter key with "Next" in the virtual keyboard and by clicking on it - focus jumps to the next field

In your layout, you would do things like this

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="Field 1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="Field 2"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
```

And in Java

```
TextView field2 = (TextView) field1.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
field2.requestFocus();
```

It's up to you to decide which field will request focus next.

Answer (score 2):

About your other question, getting the text to auto-erase, you should include it in `android:hint` instead of `android:text`.