# Android edittext key return goes to next text

Tags: android, key, android-edittext

I have a series of EditText entries and would like it so when the user hits the enter key it will go to the next Editext.  I know how do this one at a time but is there a way to tell all of the edittext controls to use the same function that checks the key entry and advances the cursor.  It seems kind of crazy to have one function for each of the EditTexts

Comment: did you put inputType="text" (i.e. not multiple lines)

Comment: see detail answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093775/android-edittext-question-replace-keypad-enter-with-done/24536227#24536227

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Much simpler than sniffing keys: try setting `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` (at least for single-line entry textviews). Read more in the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) for TextView.

*Update:* `singleLine` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) now, but you can leave it out. It's the default behavior for editable text as long as you don't explicitly set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`, and `inputType` overrides the suggested `singleLine` replacement of `maxLines="1"` for editable text anyways.

Comment: [android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) is not depreciated. It's the [singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) constant that wa depreciated

Comment: @Olumide: Interesting - if that's true then it's a doc error: "This attribute is deprecated. Use maxLines instead to change the layout of a static text, and use the textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute instead for editable text views."

Answer (score 8):

For an alternative or a newer approach for the answer given from Yoni...

Since `singleLine` is considereded [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine), we can set manually to `android:maxLines="1"` with `android:inputType="text"`.

Small explanation:

- We use `android:inputType="text"` to specifically treat the input as [plain text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType).
- And we use `android:maxLines="1"` to set the max lines of the text to 1 (as it suggests).

Using `maxLines="1"` alone, will not cause any effect, but `inputType="text"` alone may work also, as Adam mentions (though I haven't checked this).

Answer (score 5):

Adding

```
    android:inputType="text"
```

in XML is just enough. When You are not defining input type, then it goes to next line.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a single event listener to all your editText objects:

```
OnKeyListener myKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO: do what you got to do
            return false;
        }
    };
editText1.setOnKeyListener(myKeyListener);
editText2.setOnKeyListener(myKeyListener);
editText3.setOnKeyListener(myKeyListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this custom style in styles.xml

```
<style name="SingleLineText">
    <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

and then set it in EditText like this

```
 style="@style/SingleLineText"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in EditText

```
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:maxLines="1"
```