# How to pass control from one textview to other after pressing the enter button in keyboard?

Tags: android

I have two textViews shown below after pressing enter button in first textview the cursor should goes to second textview. How?

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_username"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pengala_logo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_login_pwd"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please enter Email"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <requestFocus />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_pwd"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_login_submit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, `EditBox` have the `requestFocus()` you can use this while clicking `Button`.

```
EditText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999131/android-edittext-key-return-goes-to-next-text), you can simply use the 
`android:imeOptions="actionNext"` option on your `txt_login_username` to change the 'enter' key to go to the 'next' input. You may need to specify `android:singleLine="true"`, as this will not work on a multi-line input.

Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions).

Comment: This is more generic. The other answers provide little scope for scaling. Thanx

Comment: This works in with how Android forms are designed, rather than listening for keypresses in the background. Android will even replace `Next` with `Go` on the enter button once you reach then end of your form.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work

```
EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText editTtext2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    editTtext2.requestFocus();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Make editText1 single line true.

Answer (score 0):

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

       editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v , int keyCode , KeyEvent event) {

                  EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_A) {

                    Selection.setSelection((Editable) editText2.getText(),editText.getSelectionStart());
                    editText2.requestFocus();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```