# React Native android: How to select the next TextInput after pressing the “actionNext” keyboard button?

Tags: android, react-native

I use react native for Android, and I want to edit bunch of TextInput with the "next" option like here (ios version):
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2149#issuecomment-129262565

[image]

I tried:

```
<TextInput
    style = {styles.titleInput}
    returnKeyType = {"next"}
    autoFocus = {true}
    placeholder = "Title"
    onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
    this.refs.SecondInput.focus(); 
  }}
/>

<TextInput
ref='SecondInput'
style = {styles.descriptionInput}
multiline = {true}
maxLength = {200}
placeholder = "Description" />
```

But the keyboard is close and open and that's annoying.

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999372/1456487 i understand that in native android apps i would use:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ability introduced in react-native .22 .

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ab12189f87d8e7fd84a4f1b92fa97e8894e984c7

Comment: By using ref and this.[ref].focus() working fine but there is an effect of closing and reopening of keyboard which is not a good app behaviour.