# Replace Go button on soft keyboard with Next in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Phonegap input type text show Go button on soft keyboard, I have multiple text boxes so want Next button on keyboard so user can move easily and on last input want Go so user can press to submit form.

[image]

And on Android kitkatt keyboard top bar  also not displaying Next|Prev buttons.

Comment: hey, I have updated my answer with a demo link as well - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Gxbhm. give this a try.

Comment: may it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093775/android-edittext-question-replace-keypad-enter-with-done/24536227#24536227

Comment: @NitishDhar do you have any solution without hack? Anyway Is it possible to change keyboard key from GO to next in hybrid app? I know its possible in native but no idea of hybrid.

Answer (score 27):

Having a "Next" button instead of "Go" for input type="text"  would not be possible with Android as of now.

Android will always display "Go" button for form input fields irrespective of the position of the field you are at in the form. "Go" is basically reflecting the same behavior as of an "Enter" button on a normal browser & keyboard.

There are two possible hacks to come closer to what you need (still won't change "Go" to "Next" but will help "Go" act as "Next") -

**Hack 1 - Hijack Enter key event & move focus to next fields**

Like I mentioned the "Go" key replicates the "Enter" key, you can capture the enter key event using JavaScript & make it move focus to next fields in form until its your last field. Once last field reaches you can allow it to act as enter. So basically Go will keep moving focus to next fields until its your last field & then will submit the form.

I have answered a solution to a similar requirement here - [How to trigger a Tab when user presses Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887544/how-to-trigger-a-tab-when-user-presses-enter), you can try implementing the same in your app.

**DEMO LINK -** http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Gxbhm

**Hack 2 - Force form validation & move focus to next invalid fields**

If you want to prevent users from submitting the form, you can put required validations on the form using java-script & if some field is not filled, upon pressing "Go" the focus of the cursor can be brought to the next "not filled" field. So in a way giving the impression of - "Pressing Go & moving to next field to be filled"

Try this plugin - http://jqueryvalidation.org/ this behaves in the way explained i.e moves focus to the next required or invalid field.

Also I think some android versions show some tab key on the keyboard to move between fields, buts its not Next.

All the best.

Comment: Will these things work with IOS9 as i am having problem with the same

Comment: Any update on this ? Am trying to change the Go to a Next button (with HTML/JS) for Android/any other mobile device. 

I know this is possible, I saw it on Stripe Checkout; here's the screenshot: http://pasteboard.co/1uyG9vOM.png

Comment: Okay, I've found how Stripe "did it", you only have to use type="number". It will give you the next arrow, but probably not what you want. :( Back to the "it's currently impossible".

Comment: @vinesh have you tested on android keyboard after applying this code. are you working on ionic ??

Comment: @rousseauo you found any solution regarding changing go to next key in phonegap(HTML/JS) or any hybrid framework?