# How to change device go button label name 'go' to 'next'?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am developing a sample app in Android using phonegap framework. In my app I have multiple text fields and I want to access the device enter button and change the name `'go'` to `'next'` for customer. How can I overcome this?

Comment: What is that - device enter button?

Comment: Mobile device 'go' button name want to change 'go' to 'next' when go to next field

Comment: if you create a html form with the fields inside of it, then the next should appear automatically

Answer (score 1):

Try `myEditText.setImeActionLabel("next",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED)`. `IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED` allows you to put whatever text you want in the button.

Comment: Am asking phonegap framework not native code and thank you very much

Comment: It is not native. It can be called in your Activity `onCreate` after `myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText)`.

Comment: Am creating text fields are using html and javascript then how can i get (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText) and am asking phonegap framework not in android native code.

Comment: If you have any sample code for that send that code and see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823308/how-to-get-next-button-on-android-softkeyboard-in-place-of-go-button-in-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               //your button name is first Go
                b1.setText("Next");
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Device Enter button name see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823308/how-to-get-next-button-on-android-softkeyboard-in-place-of-go-button-in-phonegap