# How to trigger a Tab when user presses Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the code from here [jquery how to catch enter key and change event to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.enterAsTab = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            'allowSubmit': false
        }, options);
        this.find('input, select, textarea, button').live("keypress", {localSettings: settings}, function(event) {
            if (settings.allowSubmit) {
                var type = $(this).attr("type");
                if (type == "submit") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input:visible:not(disabled):not([readonly])");
                var idx = inputs.index(this);
                if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
                    idx = -1;
                } else {
                    inputs[idx + 1].focus(); // handles submit buttons
                }
                try {
                    inputs[idx + 1].select();
                }
                catch (err) {
                    // handle objects not offering select
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

My questions are:

1. I want this script also work on select (dropdown), textarea, button[not with type=submit]. It is working great on textarea, and buttons[not with type=submit] but it is not working with select(dropdown).
2. I found out that this script failed to move to next input when passing a disabled input. For example I have three input, qty, qtyConv and memo. all of them are textfields, but qtyConv is disabled. When I am in qty and I press enter, I could not move to memo.

Any help to improve this script to meet my requirements?

Thank you in advance.

Daniel

## Solution: use keydown instead of keypress as suggested by Nitish Dhar.

Comment: Post this in a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**. And post your html markup.

Comment: I am not an expert, apologise for mistakes. I am not quite understand how jsfiddle works, since my project is a bit complex and written in yii. I don't know how to translate to jsfiddle. Hence, I create a simple scenarioin here http://jsfiddle.net/3g3r6/. But, I am sure that my yii is correct if I am having all textfields and no disabled on any textfield, it is working as expected

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of adding "SOLVED" to the question title, please mark the answer that helped you as "Accepted" (green tick below the score). See [FAQ: What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: To follow on from what @Kos has said, if the existing answers do not answer the question, you can always answer it yourself and mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couple of things -

1. **Selector** being used is wrong. The selector defined is wrong in terms of looking for the not disabled ones, use this one instead -

   ```
   $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])");
   ```
2. **Firefox 29.0** has a **bug with keypress on select** inputs, **use keydown** instead - Select is not working for you in firefox due to a bug (or not a bug) where they don't listen to keypress when its on a select input - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/998291.

**WORKING DEMO** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Gxbhm (works in chrome & FF as well)

**Complete Code**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.enterAsTab = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            'allowSubmit': false
        }, options);
        $(this).find('input, select, textarea, button').live("keydown", {localSettings: settings}, function(event) {
            if (settings.allowSubmit) {
                var type = $(this).attr("type");
                if (type == "submit") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])");
                var idx = inputs.index(this);
                if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
                    idx = -1;
                } else {
                    inputs[idx + 1].focus(); // handles submit buttons
                }
                try {
                    inputs[idx + 1].select();
                }
                catch (err) {
                    // handle objects not offering select
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#form").enterAsTab({ 'allowSubmit': true});
```

Comment: Great. thank you so much. But, I am still getting the select not working. Unlike your solution. How can I debug it?

Comment: @adinugro - what is your jquery version & which browser are you using?

Comment: @adinugro - I moved to jquery version 1.7 in my demo & now using live. Still my code works. Can you update your question with the HTML code you are using.

Comment: You are right. It is working fine on chrome. But problem is in Firefox 29.0.1. I am using yii 1.1.14 which I believe is using jQuery 1.9.2.

Comment: @adinugro - dude telling me which browser you are using will be useful.

Comment: It is working on Chrome. But, I was testing it using Firefox 29.0.1. My jQuery is 1.9.2 as it is used by Yii! framework. When you are asking me about the browser, I checked it using Chrome and works.

Comment: I tried your code on Firefox 29.0.1 and found out not working well. Is that the problem with the browser?

Comment: @adinugro - checking.. looks like select is not handled by firefox properly.

Comment: @adinugro - finally figured it out. have updated the answer. just use "keydown" event instead of "keypress" as firefox 29 has a bug related to keypress. its working in firefox now.

Comment: mine worked by replacing `.live("kwydown` with `.bind("keydown`