# Javascript/Cordova keyboard control

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to get access to the mobile keyboard in a cordova app so that while the user is signing up, they can just jump to the next input on the keyboard. For example, on iOS native apps, you have access to change the "return" button to "next" or "go."

I've looked at the [Ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-plugin-keyboard) but as far as I can see it doesn't allow you to do what I'm trying to do. Is there a way I can change those buttons with js/is there another plugin I can do that with?

Comment: I'm assuming this is still the case: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470439/replace-go-button-on-soft-keyboard-with-next-in-phonegap) [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823308/how-to-get-next-button-on-android-softkeyboard-in-place-of-go-button-in-phonegap). That said, I have seen what appears to be a "next" button before, so these may be outdated now.

Comment: @TheMintyMate the second link was the correct direction to head in, thanks!

Comment: No problem! :-) I'm going to write a proper answer, to complete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some potential resources for keyboard control:
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470439/replace-go-button-on-soft-keyboard-with-next-in-phonegap)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823308/how-to-get-next-button-on-android-softkeyboard-in-place-of-go-button-in-phonegap)
[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728166/programatically-focus-on-next-input-field-in-mobile-safari)

**In summary:** On most devices it show a "next" button when adding the attribute `tabindex` to each input, incrementing in order. Otherwise it is generally suggested to set an input as the browser's default focus, or to detect when the user clicks "ok" and move the focus after that event (key code for "ok"/"enter" is **13**).