# Ionic 1: Override the Go button in Android and iOS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a form contains multiple fields and a submit button at the end. I want to override/implement the `Go` button on both Android and iOS. So that it moves to the next input field and if the user is on the last field, then it will run the same method of the submit button. How can I do this on ionic or angular?

Comment: Its basically the HTML input type that determinates that. So for example the input type number gives you a next button which moves to another field, and input type text gives you that go. Having that in mind, i dont think you can change it

Comment: And also, go button acts weird, i.e. you cant really say which ng-click will go button fire, but in my experience it fires the first ng-click it finds below forms. So if you have 2 buttons with methods, go is always going to run the first one even if you want it to run the 2nd sometimes.
Anyway I upvoted your question cause I find it interesting, lets hope someone answers but I doubt you'll be able to change that without changing the core of ionic keyboard plugin

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-the-keyboard-go-button-to-act-like-the-app-submit-was-clicked/5305/2

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470439/replace-go-button-on-soft-keyboard-with-next-in-phonegap